# How to send data from Activity to other two fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a EditText in my main Activity i want to send the String to other fragments. I did use the interface .but i don't how to properly initiate it or instead of using interface is there any other way for communication between activity and fragments:
this how i tried it but my listener is always null can any one correct me

```
  public interface OnEditTextListener{
    void EditTextListener(String searchText);
}

public void setEditListener(OnEditTextListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

if (mListener != null){
 mListener.EditTextListener(search_bar.getText())
 }
```

My View pager and fragment init:

```
     private void setUpViewPager(){

    SectionPagerAdapter adapter = new SectionPagerAdapter(this);
    adapter.addFragment(new ProfileSearchFragment());
    adapter.addFragment(new TemplateSearchTagsFragment());
    ViewPager2 viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.search_viewpager);
    viewPager2.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

In my Fragment i extended my implementation:

```
public class ProfileSearchFragment extends Fragment implements SearchActivity.OnEditTextListener {
 @Override
public void EditTextListener(String searchText ) {

    Log.d(TAG, "EditTextListener: " + searchText);
}
```

Can anyone help me understand how to use interface properly for the communication between activity and fragments. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
private OnEditTextListener mProfileSearchFragment;
private OnEditTextListener mTemplateSearchTagsFragment;

private void setUpViewPager(){
    SectionPagerAdapter adapter = new SectionPagerAdapter(this);
    
    mProfileSearchFragment = new ProfileSearchFragment();
    mTemplateSearchTagsFragment = new TemplateSearchTagsFragment();

    adapter.addFragment((Fragment) mProfileSearchFragment);
    adapter.addFragment((Fragment) mTemplateSearchTagsFragment);

    ViewPager2 viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.search_viewpager);
    viewPager2.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Above is the initial step when you want to send data from activity to fragment using interface

And when you want to send it. you just need to called:

```
mProfileSearchFragment.EditTextListener(text);
```

or

```
mTemplateSearchTagsFragment.EditTextListener(text);
```

Hope that help :)

Comment: Thanks but i couldn't use the data to populate my array list or recyclerview but thanks for the help